# MySQL - Select records that dont start with a letter?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select records in a mysql database that does not start with a letter, a-z? If so, how? I just want to grab records with the first character that is either a number, or a pound sign, or anything in the first character that is not a-z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout MySQL `REGEXP` operator - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, try

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP '^[0-9€]'
```

Comment: John needs records that don't starts with A-Z. I think that better solution is a pattern like `[^\w]+`. To be more clear: `\w` means any word character (alphanumeric & underscore). So if you want to include records that begines with underscore, use `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Yep, best answer would be then REGEXP '^[^\w]+' meaning anything that has the first character that is NOT a letter.